# Contact still visible in Whatsapp after deleting out of my contactlist from my phone

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I deleted a contact/number out of my contact list from my smart phone. But if I open WhatsApp I can still see that same contact/person that I deleted earlier. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the contact list and deleting past chats in WhatsApp, as described in their [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/23179277)?

Comment: @Chahk : that still does not helps. The contact is still visible. I am just not sure what is goning on here

Answer (score 3):

According to WhatsApp's [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/23179277), you may need to refresh the list.  You also will still see the deleted contact if there are past chats you've had with that contact.

> **How do I delete a contact?**
>
> The contacts that you see in WhatsApp come from your address book.
>   There is no way to directly edit the Select contact screen.
>
> To delete a contact from the WhatsApp contact list, you will need to
>   delete the contact from your phone's address book.
>
> In order to find the WhatsApp contact in your phone's address book:
>
> - Find the contact in the Select contact page.
> - Tap on the contact.
> - Then tap on the name at the top.
> - On the Contact info page, go to [Menu button] > [View in address book].
> - From there you can find the option to delete the contact from your address book.
>
> Then, refresh your WhatsApp contact list by opening WhatsApp >
>   [Compose button] > [Menu button] > [Refresh]
>
> If you still see the contact, it is likely that you are seeing the
>   conversation on your Chats screen. Simply tap and hold on the contact
>   and then select [Delete chat] to delete a chat.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me. Could you please say about what might be wrong or how to get it done?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a contact from the list still may not be of great help, because, the contact's new messages will show up in with his/her unsaved contact number. The best choice would be to block the contact.