# Removing contact's number from Whatsapp

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, whatsapp-messenger

I have removed a contact's number from Contacts. Also blocked the number on Whatsapp but number is still there in Whatsapp. How to remove it from there as well?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57447/contact-still-visible-in-whatsapp-after-deleting-out-of-my-contactlist-from-my-p) posted 3 years ago. I verified that the steps outlined in that [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57448/86358) still work by deleting a contact on my phone and following the instructions.