# WhatsApp still shows deleted contacts

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

- I got my new Android phone.
- I added my personal GMail account to the Gmail app which synced my ~100 personal contacts from Google.
- I installed WhatsApp.
- I installed Outlook for Android.
- I added my work mail account and did not uncheck "sync contacts" before first sync.
- Only after I saw the ~100k work contacts in my phone I disabled "sync contacts" for my work email and as far as I see, all work contacts were correctly removed from the Android contact list.
- However, in WhatsApp some of them (presumably those with a mobile number and WhatsApp) are still visible.
- [I tried the "Refresh list" option in WhatsApp, but they are still visible.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57447/contact-still-visible-in-whatsapp-after-deleting-out-of-my-contactlist-from-my-p)
- Also, there are no chats with these "contacts", since the contacts only got onto my phone by accident and they don't have my mobile number.
- [It seems I am not the only one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181543/whatsapp-wont-delete-a-contact).

Why are they still visible in WhatsApp and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

Even I had the same problem. I removed all the contacts from my phone address book but it would still show in my Whatsapp. Finally I figured it, though the phone address too does not show the contacts, if auto sync is on, it will still show. In my Phone, I went to Phonebook → Open Account settings → and turned off Auto Sync. That worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  A deleted Android contact showing in WhatsApp (and in Signal too!), WhatsApp refresh method not working, etc.
After digging around a bit, the solution was to uninstall Signal. That got rid of WhatsApp contact too.  Now I have to reinstall Signal...

Comment: Thanks!! Signal was indeed the root cause for those shadow contacts on my WhatsApp. This had been bugging me for months.