# Cannot delete a WhatsApp contact

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

Firstly, I tried to delete the contact in WhatsApp. It lagged a bit and it didn't ask me a prompt to delete the contact. (It's only for that specific contact, the rest works fine.) Then, I went to my contacts app and delete it there but the same thing, it won't delete at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Delete cache of Whatsapp, may help

Comment: If you've also got Signal installed, it's the most probable cause for those persistent shadow contacts in WhatsApp. See: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214769/391775